# How to print route lists in Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing, laravel-9

I wonder is it possible to print all route lists in a Blade, just like the way we see them in terminal after typing `php artisan route:list`

So in that case we just need a table with these headers:

```
Domain

Method

URI

Middleware

Name

Action
```

But I don't mean inserting all the route data in a table and then get results.

I wonder can we print the required information automatically or not?

Answer (score 1):

`\Artisan::call('route:list');` will not work, as it is written to print the routes list in cli and return `0` in controller.

```
protected $router;

public function __construct(\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router)
{
    $this->router = $router;
}

public function index()
{
    $routes = collect($this->router->getRoutes())->map(function ($route) {
        return $this->getRouteInformation($route);
    })->filter()->all();
    dd($routes);
}

protected function getRouteInformation(\Illuminate\Routing\Route $route)
{
    return [
        'domain' => $route->domain(),
        'method' => implode('|', $route->methods()),
        'uri' => $route->uri(),
        'name' => $route->getName(),
        'action' => ltrim($route->getActionName(), '\\'),
        'middleware' => $this->get_middleware($route),
        'vendor' => $this->isVendorRoute($route),
    ];
}

protected function isVendorRoute(\Illuminate\Routing\Route $route)
{
    if ($route->action['uses'] instanceof \Closure) {
        $path = (new \ReflectionFunction($route->action['uses']))->getFileName();
    } elseif (is_string($route->action['uses']) && str_contains($route->action['uses'], 'SerializableClosure')) {
        return false;
    } elseif (is_string($route->action['uses'])) {
        if ($this->isFrameworkController($route)) {
            return false;
        }
        $path = (new \ReflectionClass($route->getControllerClass()))->getFileName();
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    return str_starts_with($path, base_path('vendor'));
}

protected function isFrameworkController(\Illuminate\Routing\Route $route)
{
    return in_array($route->getControllerClass(), [
        '\Illuminate\Routing\RedirectController',
        '\Illuminate\Routing\ViewController',
    ], true);
}

protected function get_middleware($route)
{
    return collect($this->router->gatherRouteMiddleware($route))->map(function ($middleware) {
        return $middleware instanceof \Closure ? 'Closure' : $middleware;
    })->implode("\n");
}
```

You can find this code with more information in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php` file.

Comment: I made a Controller including the codes you that wrote and call it like this: `Route::get('/route-lists', [RouteController::class, 'index']);` But it returns this error: **syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)**  which is referring to this line: `public function __construct(protected \Illuminate\Routing\Router $router)`

Comment: which php version you are using? above code is return in php 8.1

Comment: I have updated the code, compatible to lower version of php.

Comment: Now I get `Method Illuminate\Routing\Route::getControllerClass does not exist.` error

Comment: 'vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php' you can find all code from the given url.

Comment: laravel version might be defferent

Answer (score 0):

In your `controller` you can get the list of routes using `Artisan facade`.

```
public function showRoutes($request) {
    $routes = Artisan::call('route:list');
    return view('your_view', compact('routes'));  
}
```

Comment: `dd($routes);` returns **0** somehow

Comment: try dd(Artisan::call('route:list')); and see what result you get

Comment: I get 0 as result of ` dd(Artisan::call('route:list'));`

Comment: Still returns 0

Answer (score 0):

```
@php  
$routeCollection = Route::getRoutes();
@endphp
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>HTTP Method</th>
        <th>Route</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Corresponding Action</th>
    </tr>
</table>
@foreach ($routeCollection as $route)
    <tr>
    <td> {{$value->getMethods()[0] }}</td>
    <td> {{$value->getPath() }}</td>
    <td> {{$value->getName() }}</td>
    <td> {{$value->getActionName() }}</td>
    <tr>
@endforeach
```

on adding this code to the blade file